# Is it possible to create PDF file of Images using Ghost4j?

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I need to create a PDF file having multiple images using Ghost4j ?Is it really possible?I didn't find and any related documentation in their site...Any valuable suggestions are welcomed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghostscript processes PostScript and PDF files as input, not image file formats. That said, PostScript is a programming language, and so it is possible to write an import facility in PostScript. As standard Ghostscript ships with code to import GIF, JPEG, BMP and PCX file formats (ghostpdl/gs/lib/view___.ps)

However, I have no idea what Ghost4j exposes (and besides, I'm not a Java programmer) so I can't tell you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Ghost4j, I did it using [PDFBox ImageToPDF](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ImageToPDF.html)

The actual code can be found [here](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ImageToPDF.java.html), also you may want to adapt this according to your requirement.

Comment: thanks for the info ,but what i actually need is to create a pdf using ghost4j .Do you have any idea on it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of using Ghost4j for converting pdf to image:

```
import org.ghost4j.document.DocumentException;
import org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument;
import org.ghost4j.renderer.RendererException;
import org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PdfToIm_G4J {

    public void convertPdfToIm( String pdfFilePath, String imExtension ) throws 
                                     IOException,DocumentException,RendererException

        // load the pdf
        document.load( new File( pdfFilePath ) );     

        // create renderer
        SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();

        // set resolution (in DPI)
        renderer.setResolution( dpi );

        // render the images
        List<Image> images = renderer.render( document );

        // write the images to file
        for (int iPage = 0; iPage < images.size(); iPage++) {
            ImageIO.write( (RenderedImage) images.get( iPage ), imExtension, 
                            new File( "" + iPage + "." + imExtension ) );
        }

    }    

}
```